# Let's Create Custom Field Template Documentation

Tags: custom-field, customization, post-meta, metabox

I've been using the [Custom Field Template plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/) for a while now, and I really like it. It's fantastic for adding quick custom field meta boxes in the wordpress back end. It handles TinyMCE, file uploads, repeating fields, date picker, etc. For really advanced stuff I do custom coding, but nothing beats rapid development with this plugin.

There is only one problem with this powerful plugin: the developer is japanese and the documentation is almost non-existant. The docs on his site in english are poor, and other stuff I've found on the web is limited.

The question: where is the best place for Custom Field Template documentation - especially for the more advanced features. I'm guessing that there is no place so lets begin creating the definitive source right here on wonderful Wordpress Answers.

Here is what I found so far:

- [Author's website (english version of Japanese)](http://wpgogo.com/development/custom-field-template.html#english)
- [Multiple Fields & Groups with the WordPress Custom Field Template Plugin](http://www.kevinleary.net/multiple-fields-groups-wordpress-custom-field-template-plugin/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [public gist](https://gist.github.com/) or a repository. You can use multiple files per gist, everyone can comment or fork the project. It is like a wiki for developers. :)